# how to show reminder notification in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

I have a reminder table. how I can show reminder at a specified time.

This is my table

```
id | due_date | due_time |     notes     | created_by
------------------------------------------------------
 1 |2019-02-27| 10:00:00 | Hai, testing  |  Rahul
```

I want to show the content from this table at the specified time (due_time)

Comment: I think you need to set server cone notification for that it will trigger based on datetime provided

Comment: @ViperTecPro but, how can i send the data to frond end. actually i want to show the notification on the current page i opened

Comment: You can create api for that like when crone triggered it will call api url you've provided and it will set data to front-end.

Comment: @ViperTecPro this method will work if i stay one page. i don't want like, i need notification on  the page which i opened